# Adding the application autehntication to Swagger UI

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui

I have Spring boot app where I integrate JWT authentication.

In order to authenticate, user need to send a POST request to `/login` with username and password, then he gets a JSON response with `{"token": "BEARER SOME_TOKEN" }`.

In my swagger UI, when I click "Try it out" and execute a request, the request is being sent without any token.

**Question -** Is there any way to query a login request and add authorization token to the Swagger UI requests?

Answer (score 1):

In this case we can intercept the tokens and add them to all the requests by using these two interceptors in the `index.html` when defining SwaggerUIBundle:

```
            const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
                ...
                responseInterceptor:
                    function (response) {
                        if (response.obj.access_token) {
                            console.log(response.obj.access_token)
                            const token = response.obj.access_token;
                            localStorage.setItem("token", token)
                        }

                        return response;
                    },
                requestInterceptor:
                    function (request) {
                        request.headers.Authorization = "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("token");
                        return request;
                }
           }
```

The responseInterceptor captures the response and if it contains the field "token" it saves it in local storage.
The requestInterceptor adds the Authorization header on each call you make from swagger-ui using the value from local storage.

This fix is for using v3 of swagger-ui:

```
   <script src="https://unpkg.com/swagger-ui-dist@3.12.1/swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js"></script>
   <script src="https://unpkg.com/swagger-ui-dist@3.12.1/swagger-ui-bundle.js"></script>
```