# How to use automatic variables in Swagger UI?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, swagger-ui

In Postman I can automatically save variables the from response body.

**For example:**
First I send login request and as response I get `accessToken` and `refreshToken` variables.

[image: Sending request]

Then by Postman test scripts I save these variables:

```js
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("access_token", jsonData.accessToken);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("refresh_token", jsonData.refreshToken);
```

These variables automatically updates themselves in next request:

[image: automatically updates themselves]

**The question is how I can do the same in Swagger UI?**

The problem is that by default in Swagger UI every time I need to write refresh token by hand:

[image: Writing by hand]

Comment: Swagger UI has the [`responseInterceptor` and `requestInterceptor`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54537896/113116) that can be used to pass values between the requests. If your Swagger UI is provided by some library/framework (such as Swashbuckle or Swagger-Net), check if it has options to configure the interceptors.

Comment: Swashbuckle has "UseRequestInterceptor" and "UseResponseInterceptor" extension method available. check this [link](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#use-client-side-request-and-response-interceptors)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@CodingMytra](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/162425/ajinkya) tanks to your comment I found a solution.

By adding these `UseRequestInterceptor` and `UseResponseInterceptor` options, `accessToken` and `refreshToken` variables automatically updates themselves.

```
app.UseSwaggerUI(swaggerUiOptions =>
            {
                var responseInterceptor = @"(res) => 
                {
                    if(res.obj.accessToken)
                    { 
                        console.log(res.obj.accessToken);
                        const token = res.obj.accessToken;
                        localStorage.setItem('token', token);
                    };
                    if(res.obj.refreshToken)
                    { 
                        console.log(res.obj.refreshToken); 
                        const refresh_token = res.obj.refreshToken; 
                        localStorage.setItem('refresh_token', refresh_token); 
                    }; 
                    return res; 
                }";
                    var requestInterceptor = @"(req) => 
                { 
                    req.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token');
                    req.headers['RefreshToken'] = localStorage.getItem('refresh_token');
                    return req; 
                }";
                swaggerUiOptions.UseResponseInterceptor(Regex.Replace(responseInterceptor, @"\s+", " "));
                swaggerUiOptions.UseRequestInterceptor(Regex.Replace(requestInterceptor, @"\s+", " "));
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

For pure javascript use responseInterceptor (to get the token) and requestInterceptor (to set the token) functions.
See https://swagger.io/docs/open-source-tools/swagger-ui/usage/configuration/

```
  <script>
    window.onload = () => {
      window.ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
        url: 'your_swagger_json.json',
        defaultModelsExpandDepth: -1,
        dom_id: '#swagger-ui',
        presets: [
          SwaggerUIBundle.presets.apis,
          SwaggerUIStandalonePreset
        ],
        layout: "StandaloneLayout",
        persistAuthorization: true,
        responseInterceptor: function (response) {
          if (response.obj.access_token) {
            let swaggertoken = response.obj.access_token;
            if (swaggertoken) {
              localStorage.setItem("swaggertoken", swaggertoken)
            };
          };
          return response;
        },
        requestInterceptor: function (request) {
          request.headers.access_token = localStorage.getItem("swaggertoken");
          return request;
        },
      });
    };
  </script>
```